# How to change permissions to the other drives in a hard disk?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I have dual booted with XP and Ubuntu 11.04. Later I formatted Ubuntu partition with 11.10 now I have three drives one for XP other for UBUNTU and other for data when I log in into UBUNTU I am unable to create or delete the all files in the other two drives (XP drive and data drive).

Is there any way to change permissions to the entire drive?

I am unable to change permission by GUI (properties option).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you use to set permissions varies with the file system.

For linux permissions it is chown/chmod , but I am guessing you are asking about ntfs.

For ntfs, edit the appropriate line in `/etc/fstab` add in the `permissions` option

```
UUID=12102C02102CEB83 /media/windows ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

Change your UUID to your NTFS partition , you can list it with

```
sudo blkid
```

You then re-mount the partition and use chown and chmod

```
sudo chown your_user:your_user /media/windows
sudo chmod 770 /media/windows
```

If you want a graphical tool, use PySDM

```
sudo apt-get install pysdm
```

[image: PySDM]

See also [Ubuntu Wiki File permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

Comment: is it possible to do it by using gparted

Comment: no, gparted is a graphical front end for managing partitions - making them, resizing them, etc, but not for managing files or file permissions.

Comment: i am unable to unmark the option mount the drive with read-only mode little help please how to change the drive from READ MODE to CREATE OR DELETE mode

Comment: in my permission menu i have both owner and the group as root

Comment: What "permission menu" ? Did you make the change in fstab ? psydm ?

Comment: in properties window permissions tab

Comment: and sorry will you please tell me how to change permissions using psydm

Comment: You will need to make the edit I suggested to fstab , unmount the partition, and mount it again (for the changes to fstab to be applied). Then you can try either `gksu nautilus --no-desktop` or the chown / chmod commands w/ sudo.

Comment: after done this i restarted the system then i am getting "serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /media/sda3 
press I to ignore, S to skip or M for manual recovery" errors each time when i am starting the system

Comment: @VENKI That sounds like a new problem, and not what I would expect. Post the line you used from fstab and you might want to start a new question.

Comment: hmm thanks for the help i am able to gain permissions.

Comment: Only the 'fstab' bit of this answer is helpful. As for the resto of it - you could have put "google it!" just as well. PySDM is far from self explanatory and the Wiki is the usual Terminal nightmare.