# Error setting permissions : read only file system on local drives

Tags: 11.10, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change permissions to the other drives in a hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88080/how-to-change-permissions-to-the-other-drives-in-a-hard-disk)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 recently, alongside Windows XP.
I can't change the file access permissions for the other local drives except for the root folder, i am not able to delete/create/modify anything from the other local drives, & i have got 4 partitions (other than root) in NTFS formats.
This is the error message being displayed :

```
Sorry, could not change the permissions of "softwares": Error setting permissions: Read-only file system.
```

Where "softwares" is the name of the partition.
 
How could i fix it ? Would be glad to get some help.