# Changing read-write permissions on my external Seagate hard drive

Tags: 11.10, permissions

I have an external hard drive (Seagate Free Agent) that I normally download files to.

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 11.10 along with Windows 7-64 bit.

I can read all of my files in my external HD perfectly, but when I attempt to do a download of a file to this drive, I get an "unable to write because of read only" disk error. When I attempt to change the permissions of the disk through the "Properties" bar, I still get an error that I don't have the proper permissions to change permissions.

I have heard of "mounting" the disk, but I am afraid of mistakenly reformatting and destroying all the data that I have currently on that drive.  How best should I safely change the permissions on that drive so that I can write and download files to the drive??

The drive is listed under /dev/sdc1.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/88080/46312 will get you there

Comment: What file system is being used on the external drive?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my issue by opening a terminal and

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Worked for me and restored my access to my USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

type this on a terminal

`gksu nautilus`

¡¡¡WARNING!! be very cautious with this command its like super-god command.

it will open nautilus file manager, then go to the HDD and  right click on the permissions tab and change the permissions; once done type

```
exit
```

on the terminal and or close nautilus; remember to this ¡please!.

another thing that may help is to install this

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

and then reboot your machine.

Comment: Typing `exit` in the Terminal won't do anything while Nautilus is still running.