# How to change ownership for an external HDD?

Tags: external-hdd, chown

I've got an external HDD (640 GB), with file system FAT32. I want to change the ownership of it from root (default) to angstrem (my username). The system is mounted to /media/exthdd. I try to do that by a command:

```
sudo chown -vR angstrem:angstrem /media/exthdd
```

and after that the system gives me an error:

```
chown: changing ownership of `/media/exthdd': Operation not permitted
```

If anybody knows, please tell me, how to change ownership of that HDD?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/88080/how-to-change-permissions-to-the-other-drives-in-a-hard-disk

Comment: I tested this and found that when I mount external HDs I am automatically made the owner of the relevant /media/<name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAT doesn't support file ownership, so you need to specify the owner when you mount the device. You can do this by adding uid and gid options to your mount command.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting this way in Ubuntu 18.10 is deprecated, but still works. With a spot of luck your external drive will be mounted as the current user. Please note though that `sdb1` may not be the name of your drive.

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1
```