# Unable to change permission of the files on mounted partitions in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: chmod

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I mounted my SOFTS(/dev/sda6), a NTFS partition by selecting it on nautilus. After that I openend the terminal and tried to change the permissions of a file. The command executed but the file permissions remained unchanged. I tried changing the permissions by using root privileges but that did not work either.

Comment: Please edit your question to include which filesystem is used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change permissions to the other drives in a hard disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88080/how-to-change-permissions-to-the-other-drives-in-a-hard-disk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through exactly the same issue. [This](http://galigio.org/2011/04/14/auto-mount-drives-at-system-startup-on-ubuntu/) page perfectly solves the issue. pysdm is the solution. The GUI has all options that you can configure.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying file ownerships might help? Invoke [`man chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chown.1.html) in the terminal to see how it works!

Comment: I tried using chown but it is not working :(

Comment: you have to use the 'permissions" option in fstab, see the link I gave you.

Comment: @wangdw *How* are you suggesting the ownership should be changed. I recommend expanding this answer to include that information.