# Not able to "Allow executing file as program"

Tags: permissions, executable

I know many will think of marking this as duplicate but I have gone through all of the previously answered questions but none are fixing my concern.

I have downloaded some tarball and extracted them using the GUI and when I try to check the Allow executing file as program" on the executable files inside...  Properties of the file say -

> Type: executable (application/x-executable)

**the checkbox gets auomatically unchecked**.

Here's a screenshot of [File Permissions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oFdUgpfXCwaDFNYTN6V3RGaUk/edit?usp=sharing).

I have given chmod +x on the files too and the drive is ext4 type.

What shall I do to enable the check box?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: After doing `chmod +x`, can you run the app from the terminal?

Comment: No, I get a error message "The program '<program name>' is currently not installed".

Comment: I mean like this: `./blender` or `/path/to/blender`

Comment: You probably downloaded blender for the wrong architecture. Whats the output of `file <downloaded_file_u_r_trying_2_execute>` ?. Apparently its the blender executable. Why dont you just `sudo apt install blender`?

Comment: ./blender gave me - bash: ./blender: Permission denied

Comment: Jay I have installed quite a few tools now using the sudo apt-get, I am try to learn it using tarball downloads now.

Comment: Using tarballs are pretty straight forward. Are you sure you downloaded the binaries for the right architecture? Building from source is the next thing you should try rather than blindly running form the precompiled binaries of *any* software. You cant be sure if all the necessary dependencies are satisfied. Thats the case with linux, in case you are a windows refugee :P

Comment: It's a permission issue, I don't think the correctness of binaries have anything to do with permissions.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. Just downloaded blender-2.71-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2 from http://www.blender.org/download/, extracted it, and all the executables were executable by default.

Comment: Yes Mike I dont think there's any problem with blender, even my  other executables are behaving the same way. I think there's some issue with the user permission setting on my system.

Comment: I was mounting the drive after boot and this was not letting me change permission to rwx. Now I am able to run things as I change the drive to mount on boot.

Comment: Hi @BhabaniMishra. If you solve the problem put the solution as an answer and accept it.  :-) It can be useful for somebody else.

Comment: Yes Hastur, I am waiting for 8 hour to be over to post the answer, It was my first post in the forums so I dont have enough reputation to put  the answer before 8 hours.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using? Because in case of auto mount, the partition should be mounted by root.

Comment: I am using version 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, muru's comment lead me to go verbose mode while doing `chmod +x` to `chmod-v +x`. This did change the permission to rwx but when I did a `ls -l` it was back to rw. 
I was looking for why chmod was not changing the permission properly and came across - 
[Unable to change permission of the files on mounted partitions in ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129180/unable-to-change-permission-of-the-files-on-mounted-partitions-in-ubuntu-12-04-l) 
I was mounting the drive after boot and this was not letting me change permission to rwx.

But the accepted answer in the above link need a tool installed, in ubuntu we can do it using the disks tool too, I did that and rebooted and alls well now.