# Partition hardware as windows when installing ubuntu

Tags: drivers, hardware

how can I partition my hardware when install Ubuntu as windows until when I want to re-install Ubuntu my data remain?

let me clarify you : when you install windows you partition your hardware to 4 drive and then install windows in drive C and after months you want to re-install windows so you install windows in drive C again and when install it all your data which are in drive D, E, F will remain

Comment: unable to understand what you are asking. Can you explain little more?

Comment: Ok, when you install windows you partition your hardware to 4 drive and then install windows in drive C and after months you want to re-install windows so you install windows in drive C again and when install it all your data which are in drive D, E, F will remain

Comment: Please add new information directly by editing the question. Your question is still hard to understand. [May be the answer to this question will help you.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201073/is-it-ok-to-create-all-primary-partitions)

Comment: Do you want to know if it is OK to create four **primary** partitions like Windows?

Comment: when I re-install Ubuntu all my data don't delete while installing, did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I understand what you want, and here is what I think.
If you want to keep data after uninstalling ubuntu and reinstalling windows, there is a nice program you can get from apt in a live cd named [Os Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller), this program, once you've installed it removes operating system partitions for you, but, it creates a small partition named files, which acts as like a purgatory for the files, where it's your choice whether to move them and delete the so-called "purgatory partition" or to simply format the partition into your main, say - windows partition. then you can keep all the files you had with ubuntu, yet not have the operating system. I hope this answered the question you did have.

Comment: windows was an example you think I work with Ubuntu after months I re-install it its not about windows...

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't answer the question you had, maybe you could elaborate a little more and I could help, I guess I didn't understand your question fully

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you may find [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/) and [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283060/how-do-i-use-my-home-directory-on-a-separate-partition) useful.

Like in Windows, in Ubuntu you can split the drive in multiple partitions.

When installing Ubuntu, you can choose to install the system in one partition
(the **/** directory) and your user files in another partition (the **/home** directory).
Then, when you reinstall the system, you can keep your user files intact (**but you
should always do a backup before!**).
Consult the two links above for more information.

Also, Ubuntu doesn't use drive letters like *C:*.
Instead, everything is inside the root directory (**/**), and other partitions are
"mounted" into some folder inside it (like **/home**).
So, **/** can be in one partition while **/home**, even though it's inside **/**, can be in another partition (even in another computer).

During install, choose "Something else" to setup the partitions manually (be careful with it, though).