# Change files permissions

Tags: permissions

I would like to know how to change permissions for all my files. I don't understand why some come with ''read'' only... I'm the only one that uses the PC, so the max permissions would be good!

I ran the command `chmod go+r *`

But just made everything readable only...

Help guys? I want to read, write and execute all my files.

Comment: you can use **midnight commander** or using command `sudo chown -R youruser yourdirectory` to change permission.

Answer (score 1):

You have read write access to all files in your home directory.

To access system files use sudo/gksu (gksu is for graphical applications such as your file browser and editor).

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Changing the permission of files outside your home directory will almost certainly break your system.

Comment: I only need Home, Media and Host folders to be read, write and execute man! But thanks :)

Comment: I doubt you need executable permissions on those files. Read the file permissions link I gave you. for shared directories, IMO, it is best to use acl. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users

Comment: maybe not executeble, but definitely read and write...

Comment: From your question(s) it seems you are new to Linux / Ubuntu. Please take a look at the links I gave you and come back with specific questions(s). The general syntax is going to be `chown -R owner:group /Media` and / or `chmod -R 555 /Media/*` and / or using acl.

Comment: yes, Im new... and I tried that, the problem is that everything is denied... I need to be the owner of my system, and I have no ideia how... that's why I asked about permissions. thanks

Comment: ok, run this as gksu/sudo (I am talking about chown) :D

Comment: Use `sudo chown ...` , see the rootsudo link I gave you.

Comment: I'm with ubunto for 5 hours... I don't know how to work with it, or understand...
Everything started with getting permissions to open a pen drive, and I ended the day lossing all the permissions! lol

Comment: yes, it takes a while to learn a new OS, and permissions and sudo are common first steps. Permissions on a pen drive are different. I highly suggest you do some reading and ask specific questions as you have gone from asking about all files, to only some files, to pen drives all in the comments here.

Comment: I run the code like: sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file, and it says the file is readble only. But that I already know... It's like nothing happens...

Comment: It must be a FAT or NTFS file system, they don't support permissions. Well you can use permission on NTFS http://askubuntu.com/questions/88080/how-to-change-permissions-to-the-other-drives-in-a-hard-disk

Comment: no man, I'm talking about files I have on my computer. Music, dosc, etc

Comment: ask a new question, post the commands, and output of `ls -lA /Media`

Comment: I got this:

gorgasm@ubuntu:~$ ls -lA /media
total 2
drwxr-x---  2 root root 1024 Mar  6 22:51 apt
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 1024 Mar  7 16:59 gorgasm

Comment: bodhi.zazen you are right, the permission don't work because of my hdd... It's a FAT or NTFS! I need a EXT2 or EXT3.
No wonder the system was getting really slower... damn! and now that I was starting to enjoy the comand line. Oh well, thank you all of the help!