# Problem with 2nd HD

Tags: mount

I want to transfer data across from one HD to another, and I've got 2 hooked up at the moment. I find I can copy from the second HD to the current HD, but not the other way round. The "paste" command is dimmed out on the right-click menu. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Likely a matter of permissions and ownership; check the folder you're trying to copy into with chmod and chown, or in gui, right click the folder to view it's properties.

Comment: if you want exact answer then you'll need to update your question with few minor things, `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk` are the two commands that will help us know your file system better, you've to paste these commands on by one in terminal. give us the output of these commands and then we can help you better, if you don't understand any of the terminology, feel free to comment

Comment: Question was: "what is the reason for this?" and my answer provides, precisely and impeccably, an answer to that question. From your link: "Answers don't have to be exhaustive" so I'm not quite sure what problem you find with my answer.

Comment: Point taken. It showed up in the low quality answer queue due to length and content. It seemed clear to me that the OP was looking for a solution to his problem. Perhaps I was wrong and an explanation was all that was required. I'm not sure where you are quoting from but " Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."  is what's [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: To be fair, yes, I would have commented instead of answering - if I could. It would also have been better had I included more detail, I was in a hurry and thought to try help the guy towards a solution in case he needed it badly. Looks like there's no need to add it now as you made a new answer.
This keeps happening to me, getting told that my answers should be either comments which I can't make or edits that get rejected on the grounds that they should be a separate answer, which... oh well. :p
I quoted from the page you linked to in your comment that you seem to have removed.

Answer (score 0):

As @kurja stated the reason is permissions. The solution is as follows:

1) Insure that the target filesystem is mounted rw (read/write) and if not, [remount it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write)

2) Locate the target directory and check it's permissions. I'm using my Documents directory as an example (replace the ~/Documents with the full path to your target and the second Documents with  just the folder name:

```
ls -l ~/Documents/.. | grep Documents
drwxr-xr-x 10 me   me    4096 Apr  3 10:43 Documents
```

3) Examine [the permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work) and insure that they are appropriate. (Note that a directory must have execute permissions for your user/group for you to even traverse it and write permissions for you to write to it.

4) Adjust these permissions [as necessary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265190/change-files-permissions) to match the requirement for your user to be able to traverse (x) and write (W) into the directory you need to write to.

If anything in this answer is unclear please drop me a comment and I'll clarify to the best of my ability.